# How can I set the coefficients in SVM manually?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
print(SVC.__doc__)
```

Doesn't show any way to construct a SVM with set coefficients, and though there's access to coef_ it won't allow assigning to it:

```
  File "coffee.py", line 17, in <module>
    clf.coef_[0] = [1.0,1.0]
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

Now naturally you can do the equivalent matrix operations as I've done in [coffee.py example](https://github.com/rogue-hack-lab/PythonMachineLearningSVMExamples), but is there a general way to change specific values in general for any type of SVM?